# Timeout on blocking read for 5.000.000.000 NANOSECONDS

Tags: java, spring, http, timeout, httpclient

I have a problem connecting Java Spring to Python (Flask), my request is sent to python and starts being processed, however it takes about a minute, only after that it is sent back to Java. But after 5 seconds of running the code, it throws an error:

```
Timeout on blocking read for 5000000000 NANOSECONDS
```

And somerimes (don't know why):

```
An exception has been observed post termination, use DEBUG level to see the full stack: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
```

I don’t know what this is connected with, since in **@Bean** I specified responseTimeout like this:

```
@Bean
public NominalNormalizerClient nominalNormalizerClient() {
    //timeoutMinutes = 60;
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().responseTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(timeoutMinutes))
            .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(nominalNormalizerBaseUrl)
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                    .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(maxInMemorySize))
                    .build())
            .build();
    HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory = HttpServiceProxyFactory
            .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient))
            .build();
    return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(NominalNormalizerClient.class);
}
```

Don't know if it is enough to help me, but I can add anything if someone ask.

Comment: You created the client with a 60 minute response timeout, but then your connection handler has a read timeout of only 5 seconds... The behavior you are seeing seems to be exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Changed to `.doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)));` nothing changed, also error: `Timeout on blocking read for 5000000000 NANOSECONDS`

Comment: Enable verbose/trace/debug logging and check for stack traces related to it.